# Strange comments in review audit

Tags: support, comment, review, review-audit

I recently encountered a review audit in the "Suggested Edits" queue, with the following comment, presumably fake, from the purported editor of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911650/convex-order-and-an-integral-inequality-over-quantile-functions):

> This is a homework question from a class that I TA. The class is
>   Reinforcement Learning and Decision Making of the Online Masters
>   course at Georgia Tech. Can you please discard it?

Here's what it looked like on my screen:

[image: Strange review audit]

What is going on with that comment? Is that comment algorithmically-generated (perhaps based on comments found elsewhere)? Or does the comment actually have anything to do with the question?

My initial inclination was to reject the edit and flag the post given the comment, but given that it turned out to be a review audit, it seems the flag is unnecessary. However, I want to be sure, plus I thought it useful to have this behaviour of the audit system on record here somewhere.

Comment: Could be a test to make sure we're reading the edit comments? I think your line of thought was the right one to take if it had been a real edit.

Comment: I concur with @rschwieb.  Your line of thought was spot on.

Comment: I don't think it's a sophisticated as that -- just the system trying to create nonsensical edits by combining randomly chosen edit comments with randomly-chosen modifications pulled out of context.